# ADF Data Flow Remove empty JSON objects and arrays when building JSON files

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I am using a Data Flow in Azure Data Factory to transform rows of CSV files into JSON documents of a standard layout.
I can't figure out how to get rid of empty JSON objects and arrays when there is no data to populate.

For example if I have a CSV like below:

```
firstName,lastName,Email,Address1,City,State,Zip
Bob,Smith,someemail@email.com,123 st,Somecity,TX,12345
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "contactData": [
        {
            "contactType": "postalAddress",
            "contactData": {
                "postalAddress1": "123 st",
                "postalCity": "Somecity",
                "postalState": "TX",
                "postalCode": "12345"
            }
        },
        {
            "contactType": "email",
            "contactData": {
                "emailAddress": "someemail@email.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using derived columns to build the subcolumns and arrays. I have been able to produce the JSON above.
The problem I run into is that if an email or address is null, I want to remove the object from the array.
If both are null, I want to remove the entire contactData object.

Example:

```
firstName,lastName,Email,Address1,City,State,Zip
Bob,Smith,,,,,
```

I need to turn it into this:

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith"
}
```

If I set all of the child objects to NULL with IF statements I can produce something like this:

```
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "contactData": [
        {
            "contactData": {}
        },
        {
            "contactData": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

but I can't get rid of the entire section.
The Sink will get rid of the empty string objects, but not the nested JSON objects and arrays.
Is there any way to do this in ADF Data Flows?

Comment: Can you provide what expressions you have used for derived columns to transform the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can split the data and then apply union to get the desired result.
- Since I don't have the previous data transformations, I have taken the following data as my source data.

```
[{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "contactData": [
        {
            "contactType": "postalAddress",
            "contactData": {
                "postalAddress1": "123 st",
                "postalCity": "Somecity",
                "postalState": "TX",
                "postalCode": "12345"
            }
        },
        {
            "contactType": "email",
            "contactData": {
                "emailAddress": "someemail@email.com"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "firstName": "b1",
    "lastName": "s1",
    "contactData": [
        {
            "contactData": {}
        },
        {
            "contactData": {}
        }
    ]
},
{
    "firstName": "Bob1",
    "lastName": "Smith1",
    "contactData": [
        {
            "contactType": "postalAddress",
            "contactData": {
                "postalAddress1": "123 st1",
                "postalCity": "Somecity1",
                "postalState": "TX1",
                "postalCode": "123456"
            }
        },
        {
            "contactType": "email",
            "contactData": {
                "emailAddress": "someemail1@email.com"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "firstName": "b2",
    "lastName": "s2",
    "contactData": [
        {
            "contactData": {}
        },
        {
            "contactData": {}
        }
    ]
}]
```

- Now, I have taken a sample derived column to find the length of `contactType`. The rows without any `contactType` would have the same length (convert to string and find length).

```
tp : length(toString(contactData.contactType))
```

[image]

- So, split the data based on whether the `contactType` (converted to string) length is equal to 2 or not. The split condition would be as shown below:

```
length(toString(contactData.contactType))!=2
```

[image]

- This will split the data as required. The `noContact` stream would have the following data:

[image]

- Now select only required columns. I have used rule based selection to **select only columns where name is not contactData**.

```
condition : name!='contactData'
column name : $$
```

[image]

- Now apply union transformation by `Name` on `hasContact` and `select1` stream.

[image]

- I have configured the sink dataset as shown in the image below:

[image]

- In sink, output to a single JSON file with selected name (under settings tab). The data preview in sink would be as:

[image]

- Once the file is written, the null fields would not be written, so the data would be as per requirement. The following is an image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This was helpful.
We ended up using the filter() function to remove empty records from the ContactData Array and decided that solution was good enough.
Output data would look like this:
{
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "contactData": []
}

Comment: Thank you.  This would be of great help to me too, however the issue I am facing is that I get the empty objects inside the copy activity, when copying from SharePoint.  I can't use the Flow Transformations in my case.  So, if the objects are not empty, everything is fine, but for empty ones, my pipeline errors out, saying that the data mapping fails - obviously, since there are no keys to map. .. What would be the variant of the solution in such case ?